# Need to press enter to complete psexec execution, anyway to emulate?

Tags: psexec

We're running following command line

`C:\Util\SysinternalsSuite\psexec \\10.120.36.219 -u localhost\account -p Password -h -w C:\Temp\FOLDER C:\Temp\FOLDER\postinstallphase1.cmd`

Where the `postinstallphase1.cmd` script contains a set of commands that temporarily break the connection to the target server. Due to these commands, the `psexec` gets stuck and the only way to get command prompt is press <kbd>enter</kbd> in cmd console.

This is a problem for us since we plan to use this command in an unattended solution.

We've tried as well to use the '-d' argument but for unknown reason if we run the command with this argument the cmd script does not behave as expected (as it does without -d).

Is there any way to simulate someone pressing the enter key?

Answer (score 2):

According to:
https://serverfault.com/questions/437504/why-does-psexec-hang-after-successfully-running-a-powershell-script

you can fix that issue by piping the command in like this:
`psexec \\target -u domain\username -p password cmd /c "echo . | powershell c:\path\script.ps1"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.

I used this for send Zabbix Agent installation on remote Windows servers with `PsExec` from `Sysinternals` suite.

This is my command:

```
PsExec.exe @servers_list.txt
-accepteula
-n 5
-h
-u "Administrator"
cmd /c
"echo . | C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass
-File \\share\public\zabbix_agent_install_windows.ps1"
```